# How I can divide header on blocks by using semantics technique: for instance: header which contain: logo image, search...?

Tags: html

How I can use section like block for logo and search? I read a lot of article about semantics technique but unfortunately nowhere I did not find information or examples about it. How I can structure code by block how it does by using

```
   <header>
<section> (instead of div I know it is not correct )
          <a href="#">
            <img src="images/logotype.png" alt="logo"  class="logo">
        </a>
</section>
    <section class="search"> 
             <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
             <input type="search" placeholder="Srearch here"> 
    </section>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#aboutUs">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tropic  Islands</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> 
</header> <!-- header -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
figure img{
display:block;
  width:50px
}
header{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #ccc
}
```

```html
<header>
  <figure>
   <a href="#">
        <img src="images/logotype.png" alt="logo"  class="logo">
    </a>
  </figure>
  <nav>
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a href="">Contact</a>
    <a href="">About US</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**This is the best structure I suggest, hope this will helps you**

Comment: Hello! Yes I'm think about it but I was not sure. Thanks. Thank you so much. You helped me